# how to grab and use existed file directly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am new on php, I already know how to upload a file from list like:

```
var file = e.target.files[0];
alert(file);
```

which file will return a [object file]

I am wondering how can I grab the known path file on the server directly? 
How can I input that known path file 'object'?
Maybe something like:

```
var file = 'file path on server';
alert(file);
```

when I do as above it shows me 'file path on server' rather than object file.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

// Define the parameters for the shell command
$location = "\\servername\sharename";
$user = "USERNAME";
$pass = "PASSWORD";
$letter = "Z";

// Map the drive
system("net use ".$letter.": \"".$location."\" ".$pass." /user:".$user." /persistent:no>nul 2>&1");

// Open the directory
$dir = opendir($letter.":/an/example/path")

...

?>
```